# how to initialize terraform in one folder and call configuration scripts from another folder

Tags: terraform

I have one common folder where I keep my configuration tf scripts, however my backend config file and terafform tf.vars in different one

**Common (file)**:

cloudwatch.tf

variables.tf

main.tf

outputs.tf

**Dev (file)**:

terraform.tfvars

backend-config.conf

I use terraform v0.12, so the command I ran in bash after i access the dev folder
**"terraform init -backend-config=backend-config.conf ../common"**

now in terraform (v0.15 and later) I been asked to use **-chdir=..** flag. I tried to use it but does not run inside dev! only allow me to redirect to common file and create the lock files in common instead. I want to initiate in dev not common

Comment: Please provide the full command you are trying to use.

Comment: terraform -chdir=../common init  -backend-config=backend-config.conf

Answer (score 1):

The chdir flag is equivalent to :

```
    cd <dir>
    terraform <command>
    cd -
```

So no you can't do that and it also not a good practice.
When you are using a Terraform commands, keep in mind that your are creating a piece of your infrastructure : "I wan't to deploy network componants" or "I wan't to deploy this application"
Each of these piece of infrastructure may use **common** components such as IAM roles, Security groups or anything you need.
Putting these common stuff in a uniq code folder IS a good practice.

You should think about using your common folder as a [module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax) and a call it from your infrastructure folders.

Create `main.tf` and add the following :

```
   module "common" {
     source = "../common"
   }
```